# Equivariant Cohomologies of Two Homotopy Equivalent Topological Groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups

Suppose that $K \subset G$ is a topological subgroup and this inclusion is a homotopy equivalence (so somewhat stronger than what's written in the title). I'm not assuming compactness but am happy to assume they're Lie groups.

Is there a relationship between their equivariant cohomologies? That is, we have $H^*_G(X):=H^*_{\text{sing}}(X \times_G EG)$ and a similar definition for $H^*_K(X)$. The best situation is that they're isomorphic but that's probably false in general.

Comment: They should be isomorphic at least in reasonably nice cases, say $K$ is a closed subgroup of a Lie group $G$. "Morally" they should always be isomorphic so the question is just about technicalities.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Could you say why they should be "morally" isomorphic? If we just had a homotopy equivalence $f:K \to G$, it needn't preserve anything about the group structure. Having the inclusion be a homotopy equivalence is stronger but the homotopies might not respect the group structures either.

Comment: You asked for $K$ to be a topological subgroup; that means the inclusion is a group homomorphism on the nose. I suppose I am under the impression that this + asking for it to be a homotopy equivalence means the inclusion is an "equivalence of $\infty$-groups" but I suppose I'm not totally confident about that.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Right, the inclusion $i:K \hookrightarrow G$ is a group homomorphism but now, if we have a continuous map $f:G \to K$ so that $i \circ f$ and $f \circ i$ are homotopic to the respective identity maps, those homotopies might not respect group structures.

But is your last comment suggesting this needn't worry us? There may be a way to incorporate higher and higher homotopies so that we get an equivalence of $\infty$-groups? I don't know anything about those but presumably, an equivalence of $\infty$-groups makes equivariant cohomology isomorphic?